# visualise html video with matplotlib animation

Tags: html, html5-video, watson-studio, matplotlib-animation

In my notebook I get some data from URL, perform some analysis and do some plotting.
I want also create a html animation using `FuncAnimation` of `matplotlib.animation`. 
So in the preamble I do

```
import matplotlib.animation as manim
plt.rcParams["animation.html"] = "html5"
%matplotlib inline
```

(something else... `def init()...`, `def animate(i)...`) then

```
anima = manim.FuncAnimation(fig, 
                         animate, 
                         init_func=init, 
                         frames=len(ypos)-d0, 
                         interval=200, 
                         repeat=False,
                         blit=True)
```

To visualise, I then call

```
FFMpegWriter = manim.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = FFMpegWriter(fps=15)

link = anima.to_html5_video()

from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML(link))
```

because I want the clip to show up as a neat html video in the notebook

Whereas this works well on my machine, on Watson-Studio I get the following error:

`RuntimeError: Requested MovieWriter (ffmpeg) not available`

I've checked that `ffmpeg` is available in the form of a Python package
(`!pip freeze --isolated | grep ffmpeg` gives `ffmpeg-python==0.2.0`)

The question is: how can I tell `matplotlib.animation.writers` to use the codec in `ffmpeg-python`?

Many thanks to all responders and supporters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We currently don't have ffmpeg pre-installed in Watson Studio on Cloud. The package `ffmpeg-python` that you mention is just a Python wrapper, but it won't work without the actual ffmpeg.

You can install ffmpeg from conda:

```sh
!conda install ffmpeg
```

Once you have the full list of additional packages that your notebook needs, I recommend to create a [custom environment](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/analyze-data/customize-envs.html). Then you don't have to put install commands into the actual notebook.

The customization might look like this:

```yaml
dependencies:
- ffmpeg=4.2.2
- pip
- pip:
  - ffmpeg-python==0.2.0
```

Comment: Thank you for answering @Roland. Given that I'm also upgrading locally some Python packages (issuing `!pip install --user --upgrade pandas`) is it possible to do it once for all, instead of during it at each execution of the notebook? I am planning to share the URL of this notebook and set a job. Thank you

Comment: You cannot do it once. But if you create a customization to run your notebook with, the packages will automatically be installed when you start the _runtime_. You can have multiple notebooks sharing the same runtime, and restarting a kernel will keep using the same runtime. So the installation frequency can be reduced to once a day or so.